# MyBatis Spring3 Mapper null with SoapClient

Tags: spring, mybatis

I have a ServiceXX.java with XXXMapper.java injected with @Autowire. The ServiceXXX.java is a webservice @WebService(endpointInterface ="com.xxx..."). When call the webservice with my java client everything seems to be wired correctly OK, but if call the webservice by SoapClient the XXXMapper is null. Why? :(

Answer (score 1):

It's likely due to the fact that the class declared as a `@WebService` is being instantiated by your webservice stack of your container (not spring) so the context doesn't know about it for autowiring. To remedy this, you can make your service class extend `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`. Then, spring will autowire it after it's initialized by the container.

That bean is in the `spring-web` module, by the way.

Comment: I use extends SpringBeanAutowiringSupport in my Service and all is ok.